# Jquery works after second click then keeps working fine

Tags: jquery, html

Here is the script which is working fine but starts working on second click. It was supposed to work from first click.

```
function change_text() {
  var button = document.getElementById('toggle_button');
  if (button.innerHTML === "Edit") {
    button.innerHTML = "Save";
  } else {
    button.innerHTML = "Edit";
  }
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<h3 class="panel-title">
  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tsAccordion" href="#tsCollapseOne;#tsCollapseTwo">
    <span class="pull-right" id="toggle_button" onclick="change_text()" style="text-decoration: underline; color: orange; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; margin-top: -54px"> Edit </span>
  </a>
</h3>
```

please help.

```js
function change_text() {
  var button = document.getElementById('toggle_button');
  if (button.innerHTML === "Edit") {
    button.innerHTML = "Save";
  } else {
    button.innerHTML = "Edit";
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3 class="panel-title">
  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tsAccordion" href="#tsCollapseOne;#tsCollapseTwo">
    <span class="pull-right" id="toggle_button" onclick="change_text()" style="text-decoration: underline; color: orange; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; margin-top: -54px"> Edit </span>
  </a>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `trim()` on `button.innerHTML` as `button.innerHTML` is giving you the value `Edit` with trailing and leading whitespaces. So, the condition `button.innerHTML === "Edit"` is `false` as it has trailing whilespace value with `Edit`. Thus, it executes the `else` block which replace the `button.innerHTML` with the value `Edit` without trailing and leading whitespaces. That is why it was working on second click as in second click the `button.innerHTML` value was `Edit` without whitespaces and `if` condition was `true`.

```js
function change_text() {
  var button = document.getElementById('toggle_button');
  if (button.innerHTML.trim() === "Edit") {
    button.innerHTML = "Save";
  }
  else {
    button.innerHTML = "Edit";
  }
}
```

```html
<h3 class="panel-title">
  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tsAccordion" href="#tsCollapseOne;#tsCollapseTwo">

   <span class="pull-right" id="toggle_button" onclick="change_text()" style="text-decoration: underline; color: orange; text-align: center; font-size: 16px; margin-top: -54px"> Edit </span> 
 </a> 
</h3>
```

Comment: @PranjalMishra glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

Just remove extra spaces in your html before and after 'Edit' or use trim before comparing.

your function is being called on first time but it is comparing ' Edit ' with 'Edit' which result into false